# El método de clase que he creado no funciona como debería

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, clase

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio de crear una clase que debería ser simple, pero, por alguna razón que no comprendo, la lógica no tiene ningún sentido (al menos para mí).

El ejercicio consiste en crear una clase "agenda" cuyo constructor sea un array inicialmente vacío y que fuésemos llenando a través de un método llamado "añadir tarea" o "addTask" como lo llamé yo.

El problema viene cuando hago las comprobaciones necesarias para evitar que si la fecha y hora de la tarea que voy a añadir es igual a una anterior, entonces no la añado, si, por el contrario, el día es diferente o el día es igual pero la hora es diferente, entonces sí añádelo.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```js
class Agenda {

  constructor() {
    this.agenda = [];
  }

  addTask(date, hour, type, location, obs) {
    let task = {
      dia: date,
      hora: hour,
      tipo: type,
      lugar: location,
      observaciones: obs
    };

    if (this.agenda.length === 0) {
      this.agenda.push(task);
    } else {
      this.agenda.forEach(e => {
        if (date === e.dia) {
          if (hour === e.hora) {
            console.log('El día y la hora ya están ocupadas.');
          } else {
            this.agenda.push(task);
          }
        } else {
          this.agenda.push(task);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

const t1 = new Agenda();
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '12', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '14', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('28/10/2022', '12', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
console.log(t1);
```

Mi problema empieza en el `else`, primero que nada compruebo si el array está vacío y si es así añado, si no, recorro el array de agenda y compruebo si la fecha pasada por parámetro es igual, luego entro en el `if` y compruebo si la hora es igual a la pasada, si no es así, añado, si no, devuelvo el `console.log` avisando de que ya está ocupada (comento que hice esto así, en vez de comprobar directamente en el primer `if` `if(date === e.date && hour === e.hour)` porque eso ya lo hice y no funcionó).
En resumen, creo que debería de funcionar correctamente de esa forma, pero no lo hace. En los ejemplos de instancia de abajo añadí dos fechas iguales con horas diferentes, y una fecha diferente (la hora no debería importar), pero el problema es que me añade DOS VECES la de la fecha `28/10/2022` en vez de una.

Por otro lado, si le digo `if(date !== e.dia)`, según como lo tengo ahora escrito, SÍ me funciona, es decir, no me añade dos veces la tarea del 28/10.

Soy bastante nuevo en javascript, pero aun así pensé que la lógica la entendía, y ahora no sé por qué pasa eso.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No me quedo claro lo de las tareas, podes agregar una solo si no hay otra existente en la misma fecha y horario? osea que ambas condiciones se tienen que cumplir a la vez no? si ese es el caso entonces:

```
class Agenda {
    
  constructor() {
      this.agenda = [];
  }

  containsTask(task){ // la logica de la comprobacion la encapsulamos en un metodo para que el codigo sea mas limpio
    for(const entry of this.agenda)
      if(entry.dia===task.dia && entry.hora===task.hora) return true
    return false;
  }

  addTask(date, hour, type, location, obs) {
    let task = {
        dia: date,
        hora: hour,
        tipo: type,
        lugar: location,
        observaciones: obs
    };
    // si existe otra tarea el mismo dia y a la misma hora lanza un mensaje de error, de lo contrario la agrega
    if(this.containsTask(task)) console.error("El horario y la fecha ya estan ocupados") 
    else this.agenda.push(task)
  }
}

const t1 = new Agenda();
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '12', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '14', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('28/10/2022', '12', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '12', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('25/10/2022', '14', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
t1.addTask('25/9/2022', '16', 'varios', 'cine', 'Ir al cine');
console.table(t1);
```

Basicamente la tarea se agrega si al menos el horario o la fecha son diferentes a las ya existentes, si alguna de las existentes tiene la misma fecha y horario entonces no la agrega

Comment: La verdad es que la lógica dentro del método "containsTask(task)" fue la primera que añadí cuando hice el ejercicio, pero no me funcionaba (obviamente porque no estaría del todo correcta) después empecé a liarme con más condiciones y acabó convirtiéndose en lo que pasé. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: que bien te que haya servido @ilo28